# Finding Android Dynamic Control

Tags: android

In Android can you use findViewById() to find dynamically added controls?

Added in a similiar manner to:

```
Button btn=new Button(this);
btn.setId(1);
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);
Relativelayout.addView(btn);
```

Thanks

Comment: yes you can .... you need to call Relativelayout.findViewById  (if name of variable is Relativelayout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this :

```
//view.findViewById(id); here pass the same id which you have set earlier for a particular view, while adding view to layout/view.
Button btn = (Button) relativeLayout.findViewById(1);
```